# IE6 domain cookie limit of 20?

Tags: browser, cookies, internet-explorer-6

I've been trying to get to the bottom of this -- and was wondering if anyone can verify.

Does IE6 still only support 20 domain cookies at this time? I've found some MS articles online that indicate the domain cookie limit was increased in 2007 to 50 -- but, it's unclear if the article is discussing IE7.

Comment: Why would you like to have that many cookies in first place? Why not just one cookie with an unique identifier in the client side and all the associated information in some datastore in the server side?

Comment: This baseline of 20 is in the RFC http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt.

Comment: I agree - we have too many cookies, but most all of them come from 3rd party services like Akamai and Coremetrics. Our app drops a single cookie and uses subkeys.  

Here's the article -- "Internet Explorer increases the per-domain cookie limit from 20 to 50", http://support.microsoft.com/kb/941495
My guess it's specific to IE7 based on the pub date